# Parameterized Complexity of Vertex Multicut

Tags: graph-algorithms, optimization, parameterized-complexity, fixed-parameter-tractable

Let $G$ be an undirected graph, $\{(s_1,t_1),\dots,(s_k,t_k)\}$ a collection of pairs of vertices, and $p$ an integer. The **Vertex Multicut** problem asks if there is a set $S$ of at most $p$ vertices such that the removal of $S$ disconnects every $s_i$ from every $t_i$.

Now, let $\{t_1,\dots,t_\ell\}$ be a collection of terminals of $G$. The **Vertex Multiway Cut** problem asks if there is a set $S$ of at most $p$ vertices such that the removal of $S$ disconnects every pair of terminals in the collection.
It is easily seen that the two problems are distinct. In multicut, a set $S$ whose removal from $G$ results in two connected components: $C_s$ containing $\{s_1,\dots, s_k\}$, and $C_t$ containing $\{t_1,\dots,t_k\}$ where $C_s\neq C_t$, is considered a solution.

In many papers it is mentioned that Vertex Multicut is NP-hard for every fixed $k\geq 3$, usually referring to [1]. However, this paper proves that Multiway-cut is NP-hard for $k\geq 3$.

Are there any results on the complexity of multicut parameterized by the number of pairs (these are sometimes referred to as "requests")?

It would seem that a straightforward algorithm would do the following:
There are two options for every one of the $k$ pairs $(s_i,t_i)$: assign $s_i$ to set $A$ and $t_i$ to set $B$, or vice versa. Then, find the minimum $A-B$ separator in $G$. Do this for every possible partition to sets $A$ and $B$. This gives a total of $2^k$ executions of the algorithm for finding a minimum $A-B$ vertex separator.

Would really like to understand what I am missing...

[1] *Dahlhaus, E.; Johnson, D. S.; Papadimitriou, C. H.; Seymour, P. D.; Yannakakis, M.*, [**The complexity of multiterminal cuts**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0097539792225297), SIAM J. Comput. 23, No. 4, 864-894 (1994). [ZBL0809.68075](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0809.68075).
These, however, refer to the multiway cut problem, and not the multicut problem.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the definition of multiway cut. In multiway cut, we have a set of terminals $T$ and are required to find a set $S$ so that after removing $S$, all terminals are in different components. In particular, note that multiway cut with three terminals can be reduced to multicut with three pairs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! 
Consider a restricted setting in which the pairs in the input for the multicut problem are distinct. That is, if the collection is $(s_1,t_1),\dots,(s_k,t_k)$, then for all $i\neq j$, it holds that $\{s_i,t_i\}\cap \{s_j,t_j\}=\emptyset$. In that case, would the simple algorithm I suggested work ? Is there something else known about such a restricted setting ?

Comment: No it would not work. And this setting is actually not restricted, we can assume that the property holds in general case by making copies of the terminals.

Comment: The only way you can reduce multiway cut with 3 terminals $(a,b,c)$ to multicut is by setting the pairs to be $\{(a,b),(a,c),(b,c)\}$. So, at least one of the terminals has to belong to more than one pair. How can the more restricted case I described be reduced to multiway cut ?

Comment: When you replace each of the three terminals $a$, $b$, and $c$ by a clique of size $p+2$, then one can cannot separate the copies with the budget of $p$  and thus one may use a different copy of the terminal for each pair. The misunderstanding seems to be that there is an optimal solution that may not be consistent with any of the branching choices.

Comment: When the number of pairs is considered a constant then the problem where the terminal vertices are *not deletable* is at least as hard as the edge deletion problem (by the reductions outlined in other comments). If terminals are deletable then there is a simple poly time brute force algorithm -- is this perhaps what was causing your confusion?